# Set active spring profile from pom.xml and integration with IDE

Tags: eclipse, spring, maven, testing, configuration-files

I work on mavenized Java Spring web application. We are using extensively auto-restart & hot-deploy in Eclipse IDE, but i noticed that integration within Eclipse is not good when you start to mix maven and spring configuration. We would like to have maven variables in web.xml which will be replaced during project build by maven-war-plugin.

Maven variable in web.xml :

```
 <env-entry>
  <env-entry-name>spring.profiles.active</env-entry-name>
  <env-entry-type>java.lang.String</env-entry-type>
  <env-entry-value>${profileName}</env-entry-value>
 </env-entry>
```

and maven variables are replaced by maven-war-plugin during build process :

```
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.3</version>
            <configuration>    
            <filteringDeploymentDescriptors>true</filteringDeploymentDescriptors>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

This solution works only when i am building project by maven from command line. Eclipse hot-deploy mechanism obviously skips all those maven plugins...

Do you think this is a good practice, is there any way how to work seamlessly within eclipse with this configuration ?

I will propably use e.g. maven jetty plugin to run it out of IDE, however i do not like to work with console in shell window - eclipse console it`s a bit more comfy.

Answer (score 0):

Token filtering via maven build does not work with eclipse hot deployment.

One option is by passing -Dspring.profiles.active="dev" to the JVM/App process.

I prefer to use env variable to control profile loading. For example, MY_PROJECT_ENV=dev.

The following code reads the variable and initializes the profile.

```
public class ProfileInitializer implements ApplicationContextInitializer<ConfigurableApplicationContext> {
    public void initialize(ConfigurableApplicationContext applicationContext) {
        ConfigurableEnvironment environment = applicationContext.getEnvironment();
        environment.setActiveProfiles(System.getProperty("MY_PROJECT_ENV"));
    }
}
```